# Safari: Cursor on input element isn't rendered transparent

Tags: ios, css, safari, mobile-safari

In my current project i try to set a transparent cursor. The problem is on mobile iOS devices the cursor isn't rendered transparent. If you run the following code-snippet on the desktop version of safari it works just fine. If you open it in the mobile safari the cursor(caret) ignores the CSS and is still visible.
Since you can't run the snippet on mobile here is a link to a [codepen](https://codepen.io/NoBlueForYou/pen/aazOwG)

```css
input,
textarea {
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 10px;
    
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
input::-webkit-input-placeholder,
textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder{
    color:
    text-shadow: none;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: initial;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="test">
<textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Is there any solution to it?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your preferred browser support, you can use `caret-color: transparent;`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/caret-color